# The implication of @search.score in Azure Search Service

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I understood the reason for having search profile and boosting results based on some fields e.g. distance, rating, etc. To me, that's most likely applicable to structured documents like json files. The scenario that I cannot make sense of it is when indexer gets search service index let's say a MS Word or PDF document in azure blob. We have two entries of "id" and "content" which I don't know how the search score would apply to it.

For e.g. there are two documents with different contents. I searched for a keyword and the same keyword found in two documents resulted into getting two different scores for two MS Word documents. My challenge is why this score should be different while both documents contain the same keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The score is determined by many factors, for example, the count of terms in each document, and the number of searchable fields in which query terms were found. In your example, the documents have different lengths, so naturally they'll have different scores. HTH.

Comment: Can you please check the below question which is on a similar subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76900685/what-is-the-search-score-cutoff-under-which-no-results-appear-i-am-not-gettin