# What is the @search.score cutoff under which no results appear ? I am getting lesser number of rows than specified in the top parameter of .search

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have created an azure search index with the below dataframe
[image: df for search index]

.
**Scenario 1**: `search_client.search('stand-up',top=3)` gives me all 3 rows from the index in the results,
but
**Scenario 2**: `search_client.search('What do comics do?',top=3)` only gives me 1 result.  (Images at the end of the question)

**My question** : Why is the search method not returning all the 3 rows in my **Scenario 2** in spite of me specifying top=3. Is there a threshold of `@search.score` that needs to be met for a row in order to be returned ? If yes, Can this threshold be controlled as a parameter in .search method?

I have already been through the method's source code and don't see any such parameter

.
Return for **Scenario 1**
[image: Return for Scenario 1]
.
Return for **Scenario 2**
[image]
.
.
Below is the full code to reproduce this issue

```
AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE = 'to be filled as str'
AZURE_SEARCH_KEY = 'to be filled as str'


from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import *
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
import pandas as pd
from uuid import uuid4
from azure.search.documents.models import QueryType, Vector

def create_search_index(index_name:str)->None:

    index_client = SearchIndexClient(endpoint=f"https://{AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE}.search.windows.net/",
                                     credential=AzureKeyCredential(AZURE_SEARCH_KEY))

    index = SearchIndex(
        name=index_name,
        fields=[
            SimpleField(name="uuid", type="Edm.String", key=True),
            SimpleField(name="Numb_Str", type="Edm.String", filterable=True, facetable=True),
            SearchableField(name="Sent", type="Edm.String", analyzer_name="en.microsoft"),
            SimpleField(name="Topic", type="Edm.String", filterable=True, facetable=True),
        ],
        semantic_settings=SemanticSettings(
            configurations=[SemanticConfiguration(
                name='default',
                prioritized_fields=PrioritizedFields(
                    title_field=None, prioritized_content_fields=[SemanticField(field_name='Sent')]))])
    )
    print(f"Creating {index} search index")
    index_client.create_index(index)


def upload_to_created_index(index_name:str,df:pd.DataFrame)->None:

    search_client = SearchClient(endpoint=f"https://{AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE}.search.windows.net/",
                                 index_name=index_name,
                                 credential=AzureKeyCredential(AZURE_SEARCH_KEY))
    sections = df.to_dict("records")
    search_client.upload_documents(documents=sections)


#create df for uploading to search index
data = [{'uuid':str(uuid4()),'Numb_Str':'10','Sent':'Stand-up comedy is a comedic performance to a live audience in which the performer addresses the audience directly from the stage','Topic':'Standup'},
        {'uuid':str(uuid4()),'Numb_Str':'20','Sent':'A stand-up defines their craft through the development of the routine or set','Topic':'Standup'},
        {'uuid':str(uuid4()),'Numb_Str':'30', 'Sent':'Experienced stand-up comics with a popular following may produce a special.','Topic':'Standup'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)




#create empty search index
create_search_index("test-simple2")


#upload df to created search index
upload_to_created_index('test-simple2',df)

#query the search index
search_client = SearchClient(
            
            endpoint=f"https://{AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE}.search.windows.net",
            index_name='test-simple2',
            credential=AzureKeyCredential(AZURE_SEARCH_KEY))

query_results = search_client.search('What do comics do?',top=3)
query_results = list(query_results)

#get query results in a df
df_results = pd.DataFrame(query_results)

df_results
```

.

If I try changing the .search method's args to make it do a semantic search , I still get 1 result. I do it with the below

```
query_results = search_client.search('What do comics do?',
                                     top=3,
                                     query_type=QueryType.SEMANTIC,
                                     query_language='en-us',
                                     semantic_configuration_name="default")
```

Comment: I couldn't seem to repro this. Do you mind sharing your index definition and full-side snippet executing the search query? Also, can you try using the REST API client instead of the python SDK?

Comment: @Farzzy I have added the full code now. Can you please check

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior since you are using a [full-text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture) using the BM25 scoring algorithm. When you query the term "stand-up", notice how this term occurs in each of the three documents hence why it's being retrieved from the search service. When you query the term "What do comics do?", notice how only the third document is being returned as it's the only document in the index that can retreive a search score or meet the keyword match regardless of what you state for your `top` query parameter. While the `$top` query parameter does indicate the number of search results to retrieve, the search system will retrieve either the top value stated or less if no other documents in the index meet the scoring requirements.

You may find [Vector Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/vector-search-overview) interesting for your intended use case.

Comment: I tried using semantic search by changing the args in the search method. It unfortunately again gives only one results. Have added the code again to my answer

Comment: I encourage you to try Vector Search. Semantic search will only re-rank the top 50 documents from the BM25 scoring. In your case above for "stand-up" the original BM25 ranking isn't receiving the expected results as it doesn't meet the requirements of BM25 to be retrieved by the system. See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/semantic-ranking

Answer (score 0):

Semantic search will only re-rank the results of a BM25 query so it's not going to help in this specific case, but I imagine vector search would give you what you're looking for. In the Azure Cognitive Search service, vector search = similarity search. Vector search is in public preview and automatically available on most search services. The hard part is that you now have to vectorize content and queries, but your test data is small and you could plug it into the existing samples for proof-of-concept testing. This repo has the code samples for REST, C#, Python, and JavaScript: https://github.com/Azure/cognitive-search-vector-pr

Comment: Thanks! It would be awesome if you could provide any documentation that suggests semantic search reranking of BM25 :).